# Get pid of a process knowing which structure from linux headers it uses

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is there a way to get the pid of a process if I only know what structure it is using? For example, I have `struct task_cputime_atomic`, defined in [/include/linux/sched/signal.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L47). How to know what processes are using it and get their pid?

Comment: Structure type names and tags do not have a representation in compiled binaries, except possibly in debug information.  They definitely do not have a representation in process images.  So, no, to first approximation, what you ask cannot be done.  But it sure sounds like an XY problem.  What in the world are you trying to achieve that you think the kind of inquiry you propose would help you do?

Comment: This is kind of like asking, "How do I find the names of all the people in Boston who have pieces of paper in their wallets saying 'I ♥ Brenda'?". It's (a) obviously completely impossible and (b) people would be badly upset about the privacy implications if you even tried to.

Comment: I don't see why this is close voted. Sure, the answer is a simple "no", but it's not a bad question.

Comment: @ales ***If*** Unix were a [publish-and-subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish-subscribe_pattern) system, and if system-defined structures like `struct task_cputime_atomic` were its interfaces, then yes, there would be an easy way to find out who was publishing each interface, and probably an easy way to find out who was subscribing.  But Unix is not typically implemented as a publish-and-subscribe system.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the pid of a process if I only know what structure it is using?

No